# Ruby: 'else without rescue is useless' err mssg

Tags: ruby

I'm running into an error, I don't understand so I can't fix, the error message I'm getting is 'else without rescue is useless', this is my code:

```
def land_plane!(plane)
    if @airport_contents.count = <5
        @airport_contents << plane
    else 
        puts "im full"
    end
end
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is what caused your error  `= <5`. The desired operator is <=

Comment: @Octopus, yes (actually `<5` is the error), but why the particular error message?

Comment: When a question concerns an exception that is raised, it is important to state both the exact error message and the line at which is occurred.  Here I assume it was the `else` statement, but I suggest you edit to provide that information. Note the correction to `= <5` is `<= 5`, not `=< 5`.

Comment: You can't catch exception here because interpreter can't even parse your method.

Comment: Ruby is for some reason seeing the `if` statement as being complete without the `else`. It then associates `else` as being part of the method's error handling. But the error handling is missing a `rescue`. I'm not sure, though, what it is about `= <5` that causes Ruby to "terminate" the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code isn't correctly understand by ruby. Try to replace it by next:

```
def land_plane!(plane)
  if @airport_contents.count <= 5 
    @airport_contents << plane
  else 
    puts "im full"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jalkoby, that definitely works now, but i don't understand why i didn't work with my first version, can you explain what was wrong in the first place? Thanks

Comment: You need to use `<=` not `= <`. Remember that it's said "less than equal" so you remember the order.

Comment: @MartinKonecny: "less than or equal".